# updating JSON Object in spring restful web services

Tags: json, spring, rest, web-services

I want to pass a json object for the update function but its doesn't accept the json object and get an error. The error is:

[image]

the code is:

```
(value = "/UpdateUser/", method = RequestMethod.PUT , consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void UpdateUser(JSONObject RequiredObject)throws UnknownHostException {
     // RequiredObject=new HashMap<>();
     System.out.println("hello into update " + RequiredObject);
     // readJSON.UpdateUser(RequiredObject); 
}
```

Comment: Use copy&paste to enter the code in the form, select it, then click `{}` at the top to convert it into something readable. Don't use images.

Comment: {@RequestMapping(value = "/UpdateUser/", method = RequestMethod.PUT , consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public void UpdateUser(JSONObject RequiredObject)throws UnknownHostException {
  // RequiredObject=new HashMap<>();
  System.out.println("hello into update " + RequiredObject);
 // readJSON.UpdateUser(RequiredObject);
 }}

Comment: I've edited the question to give you an example.

Comment: Did you tried using [@RequestBody](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) annotation prefixed to `JSONObject RequiredObject`? Also you're missing @RequestMapping... Last your variables should not use a Capital letter (but this is code convention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to receive the body of your request as a @RequestBody and you can receive this json object as a User object directly

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/UpdateUser/", method = RequestMethod.PUT , 
consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
public void UpdateUser(@RequestBody User user) throws UnknownHostException { 
// RequiredObject=new HashMap<>(); 
System.out.println("hello into update " + RequiredObject); 
//readJSON.UpdateUser(RequiredObject); 
}
```